# Curl - 7.21.5 HTTP request cancellation

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I am using curl - 7.21.5 to issue HTTP requests to fetch data segments. Under bad channel conditions I will be forced to cancel the issued HTTP request.

My Question: When I cancel a HTTP request do I receive 0 bytes? or do I receive a portion of the requested segment?

Example: I issued a HTTP request for 1 MB segment. After 3 seconds I decided to cancel the request. Do I receive a portion of the requested segment after cancellation or do I receive 0 bytes ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be easy to test?

Answer (score 0):

You might have received a portion of the request by the time you cancel the request since libcurl delivers data to your callback as soon as it gets any.